# I want to using Cecil to create an Action<,> , but i don`t know how add genericity parameter

Tags: c#, delegates, action, cil, mono.cecil

I want to add an `Action<,>` filed On my class create by using `Mono.cecill`.

But i can`t get the type of uncertainty.

How do i create it?

I wrote it like this, but it's wrong:

```
var tmpFieldDefinition = (FieldDefinition) methodAttributes.Body.Instructions[2].Operand;

TypeReference tmpAction = module.ImportReference(typeof(Action<,>));

var gp = new GenericParameter(tmpFieldDefinition.FieldType);

tmpAction.GenericParameters[0] = gp;
tmpAction.GenericParameters[1] = gp;

CreateAngValueChangeEventField(typeDefinition, $"{name}ValueChange", tmpAction);
```

What I expect is:

```
public Action<string, string> OnDataModeTestStr2ValueChange;
```

But the generated:

```
public Action<,> OnDataModeTestStr2ValueChange;
```

Regards.

Comment: What's "*wrong*"?

Comment: So what I expect is :  public Action<string, string> OnDataModeTestStr2ValueChange;
But the generated : public Action<, > OnDataModeTestStr2ValueChange;

Comment: I don't know *mono.cecil* nor what is done here, but: `typeof(Action<string, string>)` ?

Comment: yes , but the string is  an indeterminate type ,  It could be any type , such as int , long ... the type is form tmpFieldDefinition ，i`m not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Import Assembly Reference Mono.Cecil.Rocks , after
`TypeReference tmpAction = module.ImportReference(typeof(Action<,>))` 
then using

```
tmpAction = MakGenericInstanceType(new [] {TypeReference})
```